# How to make teeth stay inside mouth?

Tags: rigging, rigify

Can anyone tell me how I can make the teeth_down feature stay inside so it moves along with jaw line, please?

[image: face with rig]

Comment: This would make for a great HNQ title.

Comment: You have to rig it properly?